# Weird declaration structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So, I inherited this code, involves some Node + React, and is written in ES6, and compiled through Babel, packed through Webpack, etc ..

I came across this line that I can't completely understand ..

```
export default React.createClass(
  ...
  , const whatever: (null: ?(() => Object))
  ...
```

My first interpretation is that if pusher is typed as `null`, it makes sure that this is typed as a Null Object .. but please share some light to it ...

PS: other interpretation is that `whatever` would be either `null`, or a function that takes zero arguments and yelds an Object

Edit: It is maybe helpful to add the previous programmer used Flow for type checking, and we figured out this is somehow related to it's 'Maybe Type'
http://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html

Comment: Interesting. It gives me all kind of errors.

Comment: `React.createClass` accepts object, but `const` is not allowed in object literals. I doubt that this is valid ES6 you've provided

Comment: We just realized it's a weird typing method related to the use of Flow, and it's 'Maybe Types'
http://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html

Comment: @elQueFaltaba, [You can post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)